# JSON Object value is null

Tags: java, json

Please find below the code I am using to read from a JSON file and display it. The file contains some rules. I want to read the rules from the file and display it in the UI. But I am getting the output as follows:

```
Technology: null
Vulnerability: null
Severity: null
RegEx: null
```

The file Rule_File.json is not null and has values. But they are not getting read by this code. Any idea why this is happening? Please let me know your suggestions. Thanks in advance!

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

public class JSON_Reader
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        try
        {

        String text = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\arathi.variar\\workspace\\Customizable_Rule_UI\\src\\Rule_File.json")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            Object object = parser.parse(text);

            //convert Object to JSONObject
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) object;

            //Reading the String
            String tech = (String) jsonObject.get("Technology");
            String vul = (String) jsonObject.get("Vulnerability");
            String sev = (String) jsonObject.get("Severity");
            String regex = (String) jsonObject.get("RegEx");

            //Printing all the values
            System.out.println("Technology: " + tech);
            System.out.println("Vulnerability: " + vul);
            System.out.println("Severity: "  + sev);
            System.out.println("RegEx: "  + regex);
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException fe)
        {
            fe.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Please find below my Rule_File.json

```
 {
        "Angular2": [
            {
                "Technology": "Angular 2.0",
                "Vulnerability": "angular/timeout-service",
                "Severity": 1,
                "RegEx": "(?=.*(setTimeout))"
            },
            {
                "Technology": "Angular 2.0",
                "Vulnerability": "angular/interval-service",
                "Severity": 1,
                "RegEx": "(?=.*(setInterval))"
            },
            {
                "Technology": "Angular 2.0",
                "Vulnerability": "angular/Deferred",
                "Severity": 1,
                "RegEx": "(?=.*(\\$q\\.defer|\\$q\\_\\.defer))"
            },
            {
                "Technology": "Angular 2.0",
                "Vulnerability": "Cross Site Scripting",
                "Severity": 1,
                "RegEx": "(?=.*(body.*ng-app.*|\\$sceProvider\\.enabled\\(\\s*false\\)))"
            },
            {
                "Technology": "Angular 2.0",
                "Vulnerability": "angular/Angular Element",
               "Severity": 1,
                "RegEx": "(?=.*(\\$\\('.*'\\)|jQuery\\('.*'\\)))"
            },
            {
                "Technology": "Angular 2.0",
                "Vulnerability": "Module Setter",
                "Severity": 1,
                "RegEx": "(?=.*(var\\s*[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\\s*=\\s*angular.module\\(.*\\)))"
            },
            {
                "Technology": "Angular 2.0",
                "Vulnerability": "Sensitive Data",
                "Severity": 1,
                "RegEx": "(?=.*(store\\.set\\())"
            },
            {
                "Technology": "Angular 2.0",
                "Vulnerability": "no-cookiestore",
                "Severity": 3,
                "RegEx": "(?=.*(\\$cookieStore\\s*\\.))"
            },
            {
                "Technology": "Angular 2.0",
                "Vulnerability": "no-directive-replace",
                "Severity": 3,
                "RegEx": "(?=.*((replace\\s*\\:\\s*true)|(\\.replace\\s*\\=\\s*true)))"
            },
            {
                "Technology": "Angular 2.0",
                "Vulnerability": "no-http-callback",
                "Severity": 3,
                "RegEx": "(?=.*(\\$http\\..*\\.(success|error)))"
            },
            {
                "Technology": "Angular 2.0",
                "Vulnerability": "defined/undefined",
                "Severity": 3,
                "RegEx": "(?=.*((value\\s*(\\!|\\=)\\=\\=\\s*undefined)|(\\!angular\\.is(Defined|Undefined))))"
            },
            {
                "Technology": "Angular 2.0",
                "Vulnerability": "json functions",
                "Severity": 3,
               "RegEx": "(?=.*(JSON\\.))"
            },
            {
                "Technology": "Angular 2.0",
                "Vulnerability": "Console Log",
                "Severity": 3,
                "RegEx": "(?=.*(console\\.))"
            },
            {
                "Technology": "Angular 2.0",
                "Vulnerability": "no-angular-mock",
                "Severity": 3,
                "RegEx": "(?=.*(angular\\.mock))"
            }
        ],
        "reactJS": [
            {
                "Technology": "React JS",
                "Vulnerability": "Cross Site Scripting",
                "Severity": 1,
                "RegEx": "(?=.*(window.\\_\\_PRELOADED\\_STATE\\_\\_\\s*=\\s*\\$\\{JSON.Stringify\\(preloadedState\\)}))"
            }
        ],
        "javascript": [
            {
                "Technology": "JAVA/JAVAScript",
                "Vulnerability": "URL Injection",
                "Severity": 1,
                "RegEx": "(?=.*(Request.QueryString[\"[a-zA-Z]+\"];))"
            },
            {
                "Technology": "JAVA/JAVAScript",
                "Vulnerability": "Weak Credentials",
                "Severity": 1,
                "RegEx": "(?=.*((user(name|id)?|logon(id)?)\\s*=\\s*((\\\"|\\').+(\\\"|\\'))))"
            }
]
}
```

Comment: post your `Rule_File.json` here

Comment: "has values"? How many values does it have? Are you sure it's an object, not an array?

Comment: I have edited the question to add the Rule File.json. Thanks!

Comment: What value did you expect it to print?

Comment: First you need to read the JSONArray named "Angular2" and then loop on its content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find the JSONObject in the array first. You are trying to find the fields of the top-level JSONObject, which only contains the field `Angular2, reactJS, javascript` so it is returning null because it can't find fields `technology,vulnerability...`

```
JSONObject jsonObject1 = (JSONObject) object;
JSONArray fields= (JSONArray) jsonObject1.get("Angular2");

for (Object field: fields) {
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) field;

        //Reading the String
        String tech = (String) jsonObject.get("Technology");
        String vul = (String) jsonObject.get("Vulnerability");
        String sev = (String) jsonObject.get("Severity");
        String regex = (String) jsonObject.get("RegEx");

        //Printing all the values
        System.out.println("Technology: " + tech);
        System.out.println("Vulnerability: " + vul);
        System.out.println("Severity: "  + sev);
        System.out.println("RegEx: "  + regex);
}
```

Comment: @ArathiVariar Glad I helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) object;
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray= (JSONArray)jsonObject.get("Angular2");
        for (Object object: jsonArray) {
            JSONObject angular = (JSONObject) object;
            String tech = (String) angular.get("Technology");
            String vul = (String) angular.get("Vulnerability");
            String sev = (String) angular.get("Severity");
            String regex = (String) angular.get("RegEx");

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I am getting 2 errors: 1) The method getJSONArray(String) is undefined for the type JSONObject 2) The method length() is undefined for the type JSONArray

Comment: @ArathiVariar 1. change like this JSONArray jsonArray= (JSONArray)jsonObject.get("Angular2");

Answer (score 0):

Your intended values are within an Array andneed to be accessed that way.

```
JSONArray array = (JSONArray)jsonObject.get("Angular2");

for(Object obj : array.toArray()){
  JSONObject jObj = (JSONObject)obj;
  System.out.println(String.format("Technology:%s, Vulnerability:%s, Severity:%s, RegEx:%s", jObj.get("Technology"),jObj.get("Vulnerability"),jObj.get("Severity"),jObj.get("RegEx")));
}
```

*On a different note*, Jackson could help in simplifying object mapping to POJOs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using JSONObject and JSONArray as an alternative. Here is how I would approach this problem, hope it helps :)

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Iterator;

// Use these instead as an alternative:
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

//import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser; 



public class JSON_Reader
{


public static void readJSONArray () {
    try
    {

        String text = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("Rule_File.json")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(text);
        Iterator keys = jobj.keys();

        while (keys.hasNext()) {
            String key = (String) (keys.next());


            JSONArray arr = jobj.getJSONArray(key);

            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                //convert Object to JSONObject
                JSONObject jsonObject = arr.getJSONObject(i);

                //Reading the String
                String tech = (String) jsonObject.get("Technology");
                String vul = (String) jsonObject.get("Vulnerability");
                Integer sev = (Integer) jsonObject.get("Severity");
                String regex = (String) jsonObject.get("RegEx");

                //Printing all the values
                System.out.println("Technology: " + tech);
                System.out.println("Vulnerability: " + vul);
                System.out.println("Severity: "  + sev);
                System.out.println("RegEx: "  + regex);
            }
        }


    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException fe)
    {
        fe.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public static void main(String args[])
{

    readJSONArray();

}
}
```